# Create fail2ban custom rule for Apache2

Tags: regex, apache, fail2ban

I am trying to create a custom rule to ban users trying to log in too many times. Trigger is the word "`CheckLogin`" in the apache log file.

Log extract:

```
[03/Mar/2016:19:38:24 -0600] 186.77.136.133 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 "POST /CheckLogin HTTP/1.1" -
[03/Mar/2016:19:38:24 -0600] 186.77.136.133 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 "GET /Login?nok=badpassword HTTP/1.1" 10570
[03/Mar/2016:19:38:27 -0600] 186.77.136.133 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-
```

Current filter : `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/test.conf`:

```
[INCLUDES]
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD).*CheckLogin".*$
ignoreregex =
```

Current `jail.local`:

```
# detect password authentication failures
[test-auth-ssl]
enabled  = true
port     = https
filter   = test
logpath  = /var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log
maxretry = 3
bantime  = 36000  ; 10 hrs
findtime = 360   ; 


[test-auth]
enabled  = true
port     = http
filter   = test
logpath  = /var/log/apache2/access_log
maxretry = 3
bantime  = 36000  ; 10 hrs
findtime = 360   ;
```

Must be a tricky detail in the filter failregex, but I tried various option and none worked. I can restart fail2ban without error, but external IP used for testing is never banned (trigger deos not work).

```
Status for the jail: test-auth-ssl
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     0
|  `- Journal matches:
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned:     0
   `- Banned IP list:
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it !

Playing around with [fail2ban-regex](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fail2ban-regex) I finally found the solution.

```
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/test.conf 
[INCLUDES]
[Definition]
failregex =  <HOST> .*CheckLogin.*$
ignoreregex =
```

Also in `jail.local` I have had to add `backend=auto` since it was using `systemd` by default